# How do I select a checksum of a table plus the row count in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select a checksum hash of a mysql table along with a row count?

```
select table_checksum,count(*) from activity
```

I am getting the following exception:

> 12:39:33 select table_checksum, count(*) from activity LIMIT 0, 1000
>   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'table_checksum' in 'field
>   list' 0.031 sec

Comment: What's wrong with what you suggested?

Comment: 12:39:33 select table_checksum, count(*) from activity LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'table_checksum' in 'field list' 0.031 sec

Comment: @user1401320 add these details to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHECKSUM TABLE` can't be used directly in a `SELECT` clause.
You have to call it separately:
`CHECKSUM TABLE activity` and you get two columns, table name (`TABLE`) and checksum (`CHECKSUM`).

Comment: Thanks, I will run two separate queries